# How do I do a project wide find/replace in Flash Builder 4.6?

Tags: flash-builder, replace

I am trying to do a project wide find and replace in Flash Builder 4.6 but it is not obvious to me how this can be done.

I have tried Edit->Find/Replace then Replace All but it only replaces matches in the file that is currently open.

There is a Replace option in Search->Search but I'm not sure how to use this if it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search -> Search is the correct place for that.
Type in the search term in the upper textinput and select your working set at the bottom. You can either explicitly select classes or packages or the whole project(s). The Replace button at the bottom lets you specify the replacement term after the search has been completed.

Pretty straightforward really, just try it. ;)

Comment: Yep, I agree very easy :-).  I was just a little wary because sometimes when using the Search/Find options in Flash Builder it launches into a search for something completely unexpected.  Also in most other Search/Replace interfaces the replace term is defined prior to the Search which is what threw me here.